# How to use preexisting gmail account with chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium for a project, and I was wondering if there is anyway to change the user account to a gmail account that already exists? Right now when chrome driver opens, its in a guest account and I was wondering if theres any way to set it so that it uses a different user profile?

Thanks

I am using selenium, chrome driver, and python